# ASP.NET web application does not run

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, iis, ado.net, windows-server-2003

I have made a web application in visual studio 2010 professional using .net framework 4 as the target framework. The database is placed inside the APP_DATA folder with an ADO.net connection for the GridView tables that I have used inside the application. Anyways, EVERYTHING WORKS FINE ON THE LOCAL HOST, when i run the application from visual studio.

I published it using the publish tool to a network share on my enterprise server, which runs Windows Server 2003 and IIS 6. I installed .NET framework 4 on it and registered it using the aspnet_regiis facility, using both -e and -i parameters. There was no Framework64 folder, so I'm asuming that there was no need to register it for the 64bit version.

It still doesn't run, instead shows up either of two scenarios:

1.Page not found error 404...WTF!

1. When I open up the web app directory on the server, all of my .aspx files show up as notepad files, instead of web browsable files. When I open ANY aspx file on my server (which is windows server 2003) directory, it opens up notepad and shows the source code.

By the way, it is listed under websites in the IIS manager on my server machine.

Please tell me what to do.

Comment: what is the connectionstring you are using? Is asp.net enabled on the webserver? what server is it. 2003 or 2008?

Answer (score 0):

`404` means you are not actually accessing the application with correct url. 
Try dropping a simple `.html` page in your web root and access that in browser. If `IIS` still
complaints `404` that means you application root url is wrong.Else I can't say much about your framework configuration

*When I open up the web app directory on the server*  Assuming the fact that you are opening  your web app directory in Windows explorer not browser below is applicable

As far as `.aspx` files showing up as text files, this has noting to do with `.Net framework` installation.That's probably due to the fact that `Visual studio` is not installed on your server machine.On your development machine you have visual studio installed that automatically registers itself for `.aspx` and other `.Net` file types so that you see visual studio icon on `.aspx` files.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, when you are sure that the aspx page is there, but you get a message like the `Page not found error 404` then the 99% of the cases is because your `web.config` contains errors and the asp.net can not run - in general the asp.net can not run properly, you may also have place the web.config in wrong directory and can not find it, or configure it with wrong version - different from the pool.

You can look on your EventViewer for the real issue and get the details of this error.